# Sync docker hosts images with local registry

Tags: docker

How can I make sure docker build will sync docker cache with docker registry?

Imagine this scenario:

1 - I create a docker image on my laptop for weblogic called:

`my-local-registry:5000/weblogic:12.2.1.3`

2 - Then I push it to our local docker registry:

`docker push my-local-registry:5000/weblogic:12.2.1.3`

3 - in one of our servers (for example host-1), I have a docker file where it uses this weblogic image to build an application image, something like this:

```
FROM my-local-registry:5000/weblogic:12.2.1.3

USER weblogic
WORKDIR /u01/scripts
RUN deploy_application.sh
.
.
.
```

4 - I create application image:

`docker build -t my_application .`

5 - On host-1, I execute docker images command and I see 2 images. One is weblogic one which is pulled from local registry and the other one is application image.

7 - Now, I update weblogic image on my laptop (for example, apply new security patch) and push it again:

`docker push my-local-registry:5000/weblogic:12.2.1.3`

8 - On host-1, I re-create application image. As it already has weblogic image in docker cache, it's not going to take the updated one.

How can I force docker to check if any existing image in docker cache is synced with local registry when it comes to FROM command?
(When I run `docker pull my-local-registry:5000/weblogic:12.2.1.3`, it updates docker cache, but I don't want to do this every time!)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. What I needed was --pull

`docker build --pull ...`

It will compare the docker cache with docker registry and pull the updated layers from docker registry if they don't exist in docker cache.